# Apply truncnorm and draw to 3d arrays of parameters

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have two 3D arrays `mean` and `std`, containing respectively, as their names states, mean values and standard deviation. Both arrays have same shape, so that there is correspondence between mean value and standard deviation at each single position in both these tables. I would like to, for each position of the array, use the value in `mean` and corresponding value in `std` to define a truncated normal distribution from which I draw a single value that I store at the corresponding position in another array `p` that has the same shape as `mean` and `std`.

Of course, I thought of using `scipy.stats.truncnorm` but I encounter broadcasting problems and I am a bit lost on how to use it elegantly. A for loop would take too much time as the aim is to apply this process to very big arrays.

As a simple example, let us consider

```
mean = [[[4 0]
         [1 3]]
        [[3 1]
         [3 4]]]
std = [[[0.84700368 0.78628226]
        [0.54893714 0.68086502]]
       [[0.23237688 0.46543749]
        [0.01420151 0.25461322]]]
```

For simplicity, I initialize `p` as an array containing indices:

```
p = [[[1 2]
      [3 4]]
     [[5 6]
      [7 8]]]
```

For instance, I would like to replace value 5 in `p` by a value randomly drawn from a truncated normal distribution (say truncated between user-chosen values `lower` and `upper`) of mean value 3 and standard deviation 0.23237688, as given at corresponding position in `mean` and `std`. The aim is to apply this process to all values at once.

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: How did you calculated truncated normal distribution given a value pair of mean and std?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier than you think.

```
mean = np.array([[[4, 0],
         [1, 3]],
        [[3, 1],
         [3, 4]]])

std = np.array([[[0.84700368, 0.78628226],
        [0.54893714, 0.68086502]],
       [[0.23237688, 0.46543749],
        [0.01420151, 0.25461322]]])


lower = 1
upper = 3

# from the documentation of truncnorm:
a, b = (lower - mean) / std, (upper - mean) / std

from scipy.stats import truncnorm
# remove random_state from parameters if you don't want reproducible
# results.
p = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, loc=mean, scale=std, random_state=1)
print(np.around(p, 2))

# output:
[[[2.6  1.5 ]
  [1.   2.3 ]]

 [[2.66 1.05]
  [2.98 2.94]]]
```